# web matrix does not let me upload all my files to a new ftp (cannot upload all files again)

Tags: ftp, webmatrix, orchardcms

I have a simple little issue with webmatrix.

I created an orchard site, I uploaded it to an ftp a/c. But there was a problem with that ftp a/c with the hosting guys, so I have a **new a/c**.

I set the **new** ftp a/c details and tried to publish the website, orchard shows me only the files **that have changed!?**

How can I get orchard to upload all the files again?

This is what I see when I hit publish to the **new ftp a/c**, that link is not much help and points here : http://www.iis.net  I tried googling, but nothing so far.

**Screenshot:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answered your post on IIS.net and was going to update here, too, but I see you already found the option!
I do agree that the option isn't that intuitive to find (personally I have trouble remembering there's a (File/options) button at all!) but I'm just not sure where a better place would be...

Comment: +1 thanx How about the publish window itself. The one in my original post

Answer (score 0):

Ugh!! Found it!!

In Web Matrix Under (File) > Options > Publishing > "Make uploading faster by publishing on changed files"

Great option but was in a very un-intuitive place! =( Does anyone else agree?
[image]